# Importing a tree object into python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hey so I am trying to run this open sourced GitHub python script that is a tree object

https://github.com/caesar0301/pyTree

I have installed it but whenever I type

```
tree = Tree()
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Tree' is not defined`
```

I dont get what is happening

Comment: no I imported treelib which is what looks like i should import and the thing is that python does import it it just doesnt recognize the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at [the examples](https://github.com/caesar0301/pyTree/blob/master/examples/family_tree.py).

It looks like you imported the module, but not the class.

Change your code to this and it should work

```
from treelib import Tree

tree = Tree()
```

Alternatively you could do this

```
import treelib

tree = treelib.Tree()
```